# Is it possible to specify a list length on an anonymous type?

Tags: xsd

I am converting an older data set to schema/xml. It contains a few elements that are arrays with default values. I am close to a solution with xs:list;

```
    <xs:element name="pressure"
            default="0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55 0.66 0.77 0.88 0.88 0.88 0.88">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:list>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
           <xs:minInclusive value="0.0" />
           <xs:maxInclusive value="2.0" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:list>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

How can i limit the length of the list to 10?  I.e., where in this would I put the

```
    <xs:length value="10">?
```

Comment: actually solved this by deconstructing what I had into simple types and re-nesting the anonymous types.  Why anonymous types?  It's a requirement placed on me.

Comment: Could you please post you solution and mark it as an answer? It would be helpful for whoever ends up on this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The base type is a xs:restriction on xs:float.

```
<xs:simpleType name="ptype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0.0" />
    <xs:maxInclusive value="2.0" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This is wrapped in an xs:list.

```
<xs:simpleType name="ltype">
  <xs:list itemType="ptype"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Next, place a length restriction on the list.

```
<xs:simpleType name="rtype">
  <xs:restriction base="ltype">
    <xs:length value="10"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Finally, the element, with the default values

```
<xs:element name="pressure"
    default="0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55 0.66 0.77 0.88 0.88 0.88 0.88">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="rtype"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

TO get the fully anonymous element, start at the top, and nest each construct into the next lower construct which references it.  Finally, ended up with this;

```
<xs:element name="pressure"
        default="0.22 0.33 0.44 0.55 0.66 0.77 0.88 0.88 0.88 0.88">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction>
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
               <xs:minInclusive value="0.0" />
               <xs:maxInclusive value="2.0" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:list>
      </xs:simpleType>
      <xs:length value="10"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```